# How to rotate a player view like what Youtube app does

Tags: ios, animation

Here is my app:

[Screen record](https://youtu.be/v7z0YHjjh9g)

But the animation is autorotation default. It's not looking very smooth. I want my video player rotate and expend to whole screen like what Youtube iOS app does. How to do that? Any suggestion?

Actually it seems only the video player view is rotated and expanded to full screen for Youtube App. But the whole view of UIViewController is rotated in my case.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I am looking for something similar.

Comment: @DmitryKlochkov Any luck?

Comment: @Walker Nope :(

Comment: @DmitryKlochkov i posted an answer in a question i asked.. go check it out